# Is there a need to restart server using URL Routing in ASP Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, routes

I'm using this article to implement Routing.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-URL-Routing-in-ASPNet-Web-Forms-40.aspx

The route registratin occours at the start of the application:

```
    Private Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.MapPageRoute("Customers", "Customers", "~/Customers.aspx")
    End Sub
```

So do I need to restart the webserver every time I need to implement a new routing?

Comment: Wouldn't your application call `Application_Start` after a publishing your server side code anyway? I've never had to restart a webserver after adding new routing.

Comment: `So do I need to restart the webserver every time I need to implement a new routing` ***have you tried it***, if not do so and you will know ...

Comment: A change in code means a recompile, then upload the library in the bin folder. And a change in the bin folder will trigger an apppool recycle. But a complete server restart is not needed.